# Remove space before footnote mark with footmisc

Tags: footnotes, babel, footmisc

I’m using footmisc for my footnotes, and using the symbol option. I would like to get rid of the space before the symbol mark, and to have the symbol superscripted in the footnote too:

[image]

I couldn’t see anything in the documentation about that, can I achieve that?
Minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage[paperwidth=11cm,paperheight=18cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[francais]{babel} 

%footnote marks must be symbols and not numbers :
\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{10cm}
This is my main text\footnote{This is my footnote}. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Both of those are due to `\usepackage[francais]{babel}`, which leads me to believe that they are standard French typographical practice. You should look at the `babel` documentation to see how to restore to the standard footnote behavior (which is what you want).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, please code `\usepackage[french]{babel}` as recommended instead of `\usepackage[francais]{babel}`.

Yes, the thin space added is a standard French typographical practice. If you don't like it, you can have a look at the options in the `babel-french` documentation (file `frenchb.pdf` in English or `frenchb-doc.pdf` in French).

`\frenchsetup{AutoSpaceFootnotes=false}`

will remove the spacebefore the footnote call.

`\frenchsetup{FrenchFootnotes=false}`

will switch back to the standard footnotes, probably better in your use case. See also the commands `\StandardFootnotes` and `\FrenchFootnotes`.

Comment: This solves only the first problem. For the second one you will need `\frenchsetup{FrenchFootnotes=false}`